# Divide an array in half, then put each part into a unsigned int using c

Tags: c, arrays

I am wondering if anyone can help me, I am only learning c and I am trying to split a BYTE array called c0[8] into 2 of size [4], then put each one of the size [4] into an unsigned int. By only using the given types

So I have

```
#define WORD32 unsigned int
#define BYTE   unsigned char

BYTE c0[8];
WORD32 FirstHalf, SecondHalf;

c0[8];
```

Comment: This is not a meaningful task without specifying endianess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it multiple ways, but bear in mind endianess (my examples are in little endian).

Using memcpy:

```
memcpy(c0, &FirstHalf, sizeof(WORD32));
memcpy(&c0[sizeof(WORD32)], &SecondHalf, sizeof(WORD32));
```

Simple assigment:

```
FirstHalf = (WORD32) c0[0] | (WORD32) c0[1] << 8 | (WORD32) c[2] << 16 | (WORD32) c[3] << 24; 
SecondHalf = (WORD32) c0[4] | (WORD32) c0[5] << 8 | (WORD32) c[6] << 16 | (WORD32) c[7] << 24;
```

Comment: Casting - according to the standard leads to **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char array[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
char array1[4];
char array2[4];
unsigned int number1;
unsigned int number2;

memcpy(array1, array, 4);
memcpy(array2, array + 4, 4);

number1 = (array1[3] << 24) + (array1[2] << 16) + (array1[1] << 8) + array1[0];
number2 = (array2[3] << 24) + (array2[2] << 16) + (array2[1] << 8) + array2[0];
```

Depends a little bit on big/little endian though..